# Rspec and database_cleaner only remove the data added by the tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, database-cleaner

I want to be able to always have access to my seed data on my test database.
I understand database_cleaner will remove everything if it's set up that way.

I try to remove everything and then reloading the seed, but when I try to use js: true on a test, the seed never gets loaded so i get errors saying data does not exist.

My spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # before the entire test suite runs, clear the test database out completely
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  # sets the default database cleaning strategy to be transactions (very fast)
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  # For these types of tests, transactions won’t work. We must use truncation
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  # hook up database_cleaner around the beginning and end of each test, telling it to execute whatever cleanup strategy we selected beforehand.
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  # reload the seed so we have data to play with
  end
  config.before :all do
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end
end
```

When in my view_spec I have something like this

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'my/path', type: :view do
  before do
    @user = create(:user)
    @user.permissions << Permission.first
    login_as(@user)
    visit my_path
  end
  it 'should have a valid user, just for kicks' do
    @user.should be_valid
  end
  it 'should be in the path i said' do
    expect(current_path).to eq(my_path)
  end
  describe 'click submit button', js: true do
    it 'should take me to a different path' do
      click_link('button_1')
      expect(current_path).to eq(my_new_path)
    end
  end
end
```

The first two test will run and be ok with creating that user, but as soon as it hits that last test with js: true, it no longer has Permission in the database.

Is there a way to tell database_cleaner to only delete the data added by rspec? and not the seed?
Or maybe even tell it to not delete certain tables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to change `config.before :all do` to `config.before :each do` for the "load_seed" block

Comment: if i change it to :each instead of :all, only the first test will pass, all others will fail saying there is no data in database found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `:truncation` for all tests with:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end
end
```

There also may be an issue with your seeds and not with DatabaseCleaner. You should debug your database state right in the failing test using `puts` statements or debugger (e.g. `pry-byebug`).

Comment: That did it man!! that solves my problem. I had been trying to debug my seed but i was not coming up with any errors. but this snippet made it work. Thanks for taking the time.